# Concatenating list of a custom data type

Tags: haskell

I'm building a set datatype in haskell and I am working on the remove function and I can't get it right, here is my code:

```
data Set a = Set [a] deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

remove :: Integer -> Set Integer -> Set Integer
remove _ (Set []) = (Set [])
remove numberToRemove (Set (x:xs))
    |x == numberToRemove = Set(xs)
    |otherwise = Set(x:remove numberToRemove (Set xs))
```

I want to add x to the set remove is going to return but I do not know how to get it to work with my custom data type.

Here is my error:

```
test.hs:13:28:
Couldn't match expected type `[Integer]'
with actual type `Set Integer
In the return type of a call of `remove'
In the second argument of `(:)', namely
`remove numberToRemove (Set xs)'
In the first argument of `Set', namely
`(x : remove numberToRemove (Set xs))'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're building this data type for fun, good for you!  If you just need a Set datatype for some code you're writing, there's already [`Data.Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Set.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a where (or a let as it only affects one guard) to extract back the argument from Set

```
data Set a = Set [a] deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)   

remove :: Integer -> Set Integer -> Set Integer   
remove _ (Set []) = (Set [])   
remove numberToRemove (Set (x:xs))   
    |x == numberToRemove = Set(xs)   
    |otherwise = Set(x:y)   
       where (Set y) = remove numberToRemove (Set xs)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are wrapping your result from "remove" back up as a set (which is what you want it to do), but then using it as the tail of the list in your "otherwise" clause.

What you want to do (and I won't be too specific, as this is obviously an exercise, so you want to learn) is to write a helper function to do the list item removal, and then wrap that up as your set "remove" function.